# Proof of an existance of a finite atlas for a smooth manifold

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

In couple of places on that site we can find the following statement:

> A smooth manifold $M$ admits a finite atlas.

Look for example here [Definition of manifolds with finite atlas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725827/definition-of-manifolds-with-finite-atlas) or here [Topology of a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951514/topology-of-a-manifold), yet with no reference for a proof. I would appreciate if someone give any since I could'n found.

Comment: A manifold with a finite atlas must be second countable. So it depends on the definition of manifold. If you don't require a manifold to be paracompact, the long line would be a counterexample. If you require manifolds paracompact, you still need to require that they have at most countably many connected components.

Comment: I require the manifold to be paracompact. I don't know the proof but I have read that if dim M = n than it needs at most n+1 charts so we take such on each component say $U_\alpha$. Let that component is overed by $U_\alpha^i$ and now we have a cove by $V^i = \cup U_\alpha^i$. So I dont see we we need countabely many components?